# How to write xpath if two text field having same class name in appium 1.7.for ios

Tags: appium

Can anyone help me to write xpath in appium 1.7 for iOS..

If two class having same name

```
driver.findElementByClassName("TextField").sendKeys("abc");
driver.findElementByClassName("TextField").sendKeys("1234");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case use `className` is not reliable search strategy as its not a unique.

I usually suggest following rules:

- have unique `AccessibilityId` for most of elements used in automation tests (talk with developers if they agree to fix this)
- If not, build unique `Xpath` with relation to other elements that have `AccessibilityId` or more unique `className`

As a temporary solution you can do this:

```
List<WebElement> textfields = driver.findElementsByClassName("TextField");
textFields.get(0).sendKeys("abc");
textFields.get(1).sendKeys("1234");
```

since you didn't provide your page source, better print it out with `driver.getPageSource()` and think of good XPath that you put in:

```
List<WebElement> textfields = driver.findElementsByXpath(<your xpath>);
```

Answer (score -1):

This below code working fine for me

---

driver.findElementByName("No account? Sign up").click();
driver.findElementByClassName("TextField").sendKeys("abc");     driver.findElementByClassName("SecureTextField").sendKeys("12345");     driver.findElementByClassName("SecureTextField").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElementByXPath("(//XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField[2]").sendKeys("12345");
driver.findElementByXPath("(//XCUIElementTypeTextField)[2]").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElementByXPath("(//XCUIElementTypeTextField)[2]").sendKeys("9876543210");

---